# How to break from ParallelFor loop at the lowest iteration that matches the condition?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

I am trying to speed up the execution by parallelizing the matching between a given pattern `myPattern` and a long `List` of patterns `patterns`. The code I have below works fine if `patterns` had only one pattern matching `myPattern` but `patterns` can have multiple patterns that will match and the `Parallel.For` loop will write multiple `i` and the loop will return multiple i's if they fell under different threads. I have sorted `patterns` in a way that first pattern on the list is the one needed. This will work for serial version below but not for the parallel How can I break from the `Parallel.For` loop at the lowest iteration that matches the condition set inside the loop? For example if `patterns[i]` i = 26, i = 120, i= 1832 match, only get i = 26.

```
//Serial
for (int i = 0; i < patterns.Count; i++)
{
    bool match = MyMatcher(myPattern, patterns[i]);
    if (match)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        break;
    }
}

//Parallel
Parallel.For(0, patterns.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    (int i, ParallelLoopState state) =>
{
    bool match = MyMatcher(myPattern, patterns[i]);
    if (match)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        state.Stop();
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a bool that always checks to see if it's true before setting it to `MyMatcher();`, and share that single variable across the two loops?

Comment: Move `state.Stop();` before `Console.WriteLine`.Though in theory it will not guarantee that it will not process some extra elements and/or that actual first will be returned.

Comment: @GuruStron thanks but unfortunately that didnt help I am still getting multiple pattern matches

Comment: @Joey is the code in question is an actual one or it is just a [mre] and actual usage differs?

Comment: the actual usage is the same, i just simplified some terms for better understanding.

Comment: @Joey so the end goal is to write one line to the console?

Comment: lol no the actual end use is to return the pattern that matched for further processing `patterns[i]`

Comment: Have you checked with the profiler if there is really a profit when using parallel execution of the operation? Because when using Parallel.For you need to wait until the entire collection is processed.

Comment: if the MyMatcher method is quite demanding on computing resources, you can split the collection into sorted bundles, and save the results in a ConcurrentBag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the [`Stop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.stop), you could use the [`Break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.break) functionality of the `Parallel.For`. The `Break` is more relaxed than the `Stop`.
It doesn't terminate the loop instantly. It terminates it when all lower indices in the `patterns` list have been processed, giving the chance for a better match to be found.

Another issue is that the `Parallel.For` employs [range partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl#kinds-of-partitioning), which is not suitable for your case. The range partitioning strategy splits the list in ranges, and dedicates one thread per range. In your case it is desirable to process the lower indices first, because even if you find a match in an upper index, you would still need to search all the lower indices for better matches. You can prioritize the lower indices by switching to the `Parallel.ForEach` method, and opting for dynamic partitioning with the [`Partitioner.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create) method. Either the `Partitioner.Create(patterns)` or the `Partitioner.Create(patterns, loadBalance: true)` will do the job. The first option enumerates the list using the `GetEnumerator` of the list (synchronized), and the second enumerates it using the `Count` and the indexer `[]` of the list. The second option should be slightly more efficient because it is lock-free ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6a533c1a364e41309394d2253ad36b2e001ff23f/src/libraries/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/PartitionerStatic.cs#L1117)), but the first has clearer incremental enumeration semantics. In the example below I am using the first option:

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(patterns);

ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 };

ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, (p, state) =>
{
    bool match = MyMatcher(myPattern, p);
    if (match) state.Break();
});

if (result.LowestBreakIteration.HasValue)
    Console.WriteLine(patterns[(int)result.LowestBreakIteration.Value]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not found"); // The Break was not called
```

After the completion of the loop you can examine the [`ParallelLoopResult.LowestBreakIteration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.lowestbreakiteration), and see if the `Break` was called, and what was the lower index that called it. This index corresponds to the pattern that you are searching for.

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SkmZ8k).

Answer (score 1):

If the MyMatcher method is quite demanding on computing resources, you can split the collection into sorted bundles, and save the results in a ConcurrentBag. Otherwise, it is better to use the sequential option

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
 
var myPattern = 3;
var patterns = new List<long>();
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    patterns.Add(i);
}
var offset = 0;
var size = 10;
var batch = patterns.Skip(offset).Take(size).ToArray();
var result = new ConcurrentBag<long>();
while (batch.Length > 0 && result.Count == 0)
{
    offset += size;
    Parallel.For(0, batch.Length, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (int i, ParallelLoopState state) =>
    { 
        if (MyMatcher(myPattern, batch[i]))
        {
            result.Add(i);
        }
    });
    batch = patterns.Skip(offset).Take(size).ToArray();
}


if (result.Count > 0)
{
    var match = result.OrderBy(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine($"{match}");
}

Console.ReadLine();

static bool MyMatcher(long pattern, long value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return false;
    return value % pattern == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your intention is to stop processing as soon as you have a match. It isn't strictly possible to always do that due to how concurrency works, but it's possible to stop almost all additional processing after a match has been found.

You can get much more responsive cancellation of additional threads by using a `CancellationToken` and checking whether cancellation was requested in your matching algorithm.

Here's an illustration:

```
const int largePrime = 137077;

public static void Main()
{
    
    var patterns = GeneratePatterns(16);
    
    int myPattern = largePrime;
    
    Console.WriteLine("Serial Matching");
    
    //Serial
    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.Count; i++)
    {
        bool match = MyMatcher(myPattern, patterns[i], CancellationToken.None);
        if (match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
            break;
        }

    }

    Console.WriteLine("Parallel Matching");
    //Parallel
    
    // USE THIS TO SIGNAL PROCESSING IS DONE:
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    
    Parallel.For(0, patterns.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (int i, ParallelLoopState state) =>
        {

            bool match = MyMatcher(myPattern, patterns[i], cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            if (match)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
                // SIGNAL HERE:
                cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                state.Stop(); // All threads will stop soon without this
            }
        });         
}

static bool MyMatcher(int myPattern, List<int> pattern, CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var nr in pattern)
    {
        // CHECK FOR CANCELLATION HERE:
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;
        if (nr % myPattern == 0)
            return true;
    }
            
    return false;
}

// THIS CODE DOESN'T MATTER MUCH. IT JUST GENERATES DATA
// TO TEST THE APPROACH WITH:
static List<List<int>> GeneratePatterns(int numberOfPatterns)
{
    List<List<int>> patterns = new List<List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPatterns; i++)
    {
        bool matchThisPattern = i % 2 == 0;
        if (matchThisPattern)
        {
            var from = i * largePrime;
            var to = from + largePrime - 1;
            patterns.Add(Enumerable.Range(from, to).ToList());
        }
    }
    
    return patterns;
}
```

Running this in LinqPad on a multicore computer, I typically get 1 or 2 matches returned before processing ends even though the input data is constructed so that each execution of MyMatch() will have almost exactly the same execution time (intentionally the worst-case scenario for concurrency).